# How do I configure MAAS to control virtual machines with virsh?

Tags: maas

I have a setup with MAAS installed on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, nodes enlisting via PXE boot. Both, the MAAS controller and the nodes are virtual machines.
I also have virsh built with esx option installed on the server.

Now, how would I go about configuring MAAS to control virtual machines with virsh? There is no option in the node's power settings to specify the virsh user and password, which are required by virsh to connect to the ESXi instance. Also, it is not possible to specify the password directly in the virsh connection string, AFAIK. Any ideas?

Alternative solutions aside from virsh are also welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the authentication options of libvirt. I have virsh running that way with ESXi:
http://libvirt.org/auth.html